# How do I dynamically extract substring from string?

Tags: sql, oracle, substr, instr

I’m trying to dynamically extract a substring from a very long URL. For example, I may have the following URLs:

1. `https://www.google.com/ABCDEF Version=“0.0.00.0” GHIJK`
2. `https://www.google.com/ABCDEFGH Version=“0.0.0.0” IJKLM`
3. `https://www.google.com/ABC Version=“0.0.0.00” 12345`

I am trying to extract the version code only (0.0.0.0).

This is what I have so far:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, ‘Version=“‘)+9) 
FROM table
```

This query returns the following result:

```
0.0.00.0” GHIJK … (url continues on)
```

So, I attempt to find “Version” in the link, so I can start from the same position in each row. This works fine, however I’m having a hard time dynamically locating the ending quote (“). I tried using INSTR in the third parameter of my SUBSTR function, like so:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, ‘Version=“‘)+9, INSTR(col, ‘“‘)) 
FROM table
```

I figured that this would find the position of the ending quote, and then use that number for the length, but it returns a strange output. I’ve also used POSITION, CHARINDEX, LENGTH, and LOCATE. None of these functions work in Oracle.

I think maybe when I put +9 after the first INSTR function, it’s setting the query to a fixed position instead of a dynamic one, but I’m not sure how else to remove ‘Version=“‘.

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql` tag if you're not using MySQL.

Comment: You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`. Also, be careful that you're using the correct quotes. It's quite unusual to have curly quotes in a URL.

Comment: Are your quotes `“....”` or `"...."`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option (which, actually, selects what's between double quotes - that's *version* in your example; if there were some other similar *substring*, you'd get a wrong result).

```
with test (col) as
  (select 'https://www.google.com/ABCDEF Version="0.0.00.0" GHIJK'  from dual union all
   select 'https://www.google.com/ABCDEFGH Version="0.0.0.0" IJKLM' from dual union all
   select 'https://www.google.com/ABC Version="0.0.0.00" 12345'     from dual
  )
select col,
  replace(regexp_substr(col, '".+"'), '"') version
from test;
```

which results in

```
https://www.google.com/ABCDEF Version="0.0.00.0" GHIJK      0.0.00.0
https://www.google.com/ABCDEFGH Version="0.0.0.0" IJKLM     0.0.0.0
https://www.google.com/ABC Version="0.0.0.00" 12345         0.0.0.00
```

Comment: I used the second half of your query and modified it:
`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, ‘Version=*(\S*)([0-9])’) FROM table`
It returns the following result:
`Version=“0.0.00.0`

How can I remove the ‘Version=“‘?

Comment: Oracle's regex is greedy, so it will catch everything until the last quote. Should be `'"([.\d]+)"'` for numeric version or `'"([^"]+)"'` for anything without quotes

Comment: Yeah, it’s being stubborn. It’s holding on to the last quote now. Currently I’ve got:
`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, 'Version="*(\S*)([^"]+)', 1, 1, null, 1)`

Output:
`0.00.00.0"`

Is there something I’m missing to ditch the last double quote?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`REGEXP_SUBSTR()`** with **`Version=(\d.*\d?)`** pattern in order to extract the piece between **`Version="`** and **`"`**(your quotes are presumed to be regular double quotes **`" "`**)

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(url,'Version="(\d.*\d)"',1,1,null,1) AS version        
  FROM t
```

where

- the third argument(**1**) is ***position***,
  the fourth argument(**1**) is ***occurence***,   and especially important to use the last one as being ***capture group*** (**1**)
- indeed using **`'"(\d.*\d)"'`** pattern is enough for the
  current data set

**or**

**`REGEXP_REPLACE()`** with capture group **`\2`** as

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(url,'^(.*Version=")([^"]*).*','\2') AS version        
  FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5e210587caebd52aa8249ffec9b13c8e)</kbd>

Comment: That regex pattern did not work. It returned the entire string starting from Version

Comment: These are the quotes that are being used: "

Comment: if they're *regular* double quotes, then that should work, check the demo please @Crimp . Otherwise, replace with your original quotes such as `REGEXP_SUBSTR(url,'Version=“(\d.*\d)”',1,1,null,1) AS versionCol1,REGEXP_REPLACE(url,'^(.*Version=“)([^”]*).*','\2') AS versionCol2`

Comment: Yes, I checked your demo and tried both of your solutions. Unfortunately, neither of them worked. `(\d.*\d)` will return `0.00.0.00" (and the rest of the URL)`. The other one returned the entire URL.

Comment: Can you retry for your data with these queries provided within the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=497fc854662fb4de176f10bb6bfe8eae) @Crimp

Answer (score 0):

You can still use use `INSTR` to locate the second `"` in the string, then subtract the location of the first `"` to get the length that you need to get. Below is an example query:

```sql
SELECT col,
       SUBSTR (col, INSTR (col, '"') + 1, INSTR (col, '"', 1, 2) - INSTR (col, '"') - 1)    version
  FROM test;
```

Comment: The problem I am having with adding and subtracting specific values is it then puts the query in a fixed position, rather than a dynamic one. I need something to search for the quotes that are surrounding the version code. Im thinking regex, which I’m not very strong with